# Printer Lost On My Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printing, printer

We had a mac mini recently that was flawlessly printing to three printers on the network until recently. Now it is not able to connect to two of them. Both of them are canons (if that makes a difference) while all other coworkers are able to print to them. 
I pinged all three and and verified ip addresses and they are correct but verified that the computer is in fact not able to print to the two Canons and connect to the lonely Toshiba. 
I did not think it would have anything to do with it but just in case I re-installed the driver when we were first having issues but nothing. I have updated OS and used brought en1 down using ifconfig but still nothing. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.